# React native in android studio Task wrapper not found in project app

Tags: react-native, android-studio

I have set JAVA_HOME environment variables. I have created a react native project using npx react-native init projName, and opened it in AndroidStudio. Unable to build this project. In Android studio it gives error Task 'wrapper' not found in project 'app'.
Also jdk used is the jdk from android-studio.

Answer (score 3):

Try File->New->Import Project, it will do the magic.

Comment: This works for me. it seems that there is a difference between 'import project' and 'open existing project'.